# Adding adversarial loss (Conditional GANs) to CNN

Tags: deep-learning

Wanted to do something like this - http://scribbler.eye.gatech.edu/paper.pdf. could someone point me to working model for this? They have mentioned building on (https://github.com/TengdaHan/Convolutional_Sketch_Inversion). However, I do not have much experience with GANs and do not know how to adapt a normal CNN to a GAN. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated too.

Also, they have mentioned using skip layers(residual layers), but I can find no indication of their connections(architecture).

From the figure given in the paper, I cannot make out where the Generator is or where the Discriminator is.

In short, I do not know how to hook up a GAN to CNN. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found anything? I need to do the same but for sentiment analysis